# Using 3D Touch with storyboard's peek and pop

Tags: swift, uitableview, 3dtouch

I found very easy way to use 3D Touch — check "Peek & Pop" in storyboard. But I'm struggling with one problem.

I have UITableView, when user touches cell all is working ok with my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        print(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow)
    }
}
```

So I'm filling data in my Detailed controller based on selected row. But when I'm pressing with Peek or Pop method `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` always returning nil (hm.. I haven't selected row, I'm just previewing so indexPath is `nil` I guess). How can I get that "peeked" cell indexPath to pass it to segue?

Or storyboard's Peek & Pop not working in this simple way and I need to fully implement peek & pop in my code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to fully implement it using the storyboard and `prepareForSegue`. You can do this by making use of the `sender` object.

By assuming that you have created your segue directly from the table cell in the storyboard to the next view controller, then the sender object will be of the type `UITableViewCell`. If you trigger the segue programmatically, then just remember to set the `sender` object in the method call.

You can use this cell to get a hold of the `NSIndexPath` from the `tableView`, something similar to the following (ignore all the force unwrapping, this is just for demonstration purposes):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
        destination.model = self.model[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```